# how to pass a function through multiple nested loops in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I'm trying to pass a function called 'clicker()' through multiple nested loops. I get the following error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

The `clicker()` function follows this pathway:

app.js --> one.js --> two.js --> three.js

How can I pass this function, initiated in app.js all the way through until it gets to the last component. Note that `app.js` renders `one` and this renders `two` and this renders `three`.

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-functions-between-many-nested-loops-lp76p?file=/src/components/three.js:0-166) is my codesandbox.

`app.js`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import One from "./components/one";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, updateCounter] = useState(0);
  let clicker = () => {
    updateCounter(counter + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>how to pass a function through nested components in React </h1>
      <h3> {counter} </h3>
      <One passMe={clicker} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and `one.js`

```
import Two from "./two";

function One(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p> this is the nested function</p>
      <Two passMe={props.passMe} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default One;
```

and `two.js`

```
import React from "react";
import Three from './three'

export default function Two(props) {


  return (
    <div className="App">
<Three passMe={props.passMe} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and finally `three.js`

```
import React from "react";

export default function App(props) {


  return (
    <div >
      <button passMe={props.passMe(5)}>Cliicker! </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

thanks so much

Comment: `passMe={props.passMe(5)}` calls props.passMe *immediately*. Instead you need to give it a function, as in `passMe={() => props.passMe(5)}` (or perhaps you meant `onClick={() => props.passMe(5)})`

Answer (score 1):

Why are you passing 5 as parameter, if the function does not support any?

Assuming you want that, you may change this:

On **App.js**:

```
const clicker = (num = 1) => {
    updateCounter(counter + num);
};
```

On **three.js**:

```
<button onClick={() => props.passMe(5)}>Cliicker!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are on the right track of passing a function from a parent to its nested child components. But assuming you want to update the counter whenever user clicks the button on its nested component, you might want to pass the `onClick(()=> props.passMe(anyValue))` on `three.js` button component. This way, the function created in the parent gets invoked on every button click all the way from `three.js`, `two.js`, `one.js` to `app.js`.